# React Native: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'r.default.manifest.env')

Tags: android, react-native

I've built an Android App using React Native; and the emulator says everything is okay.

But after I built app-release and installed it, I got an error saying `unfortunately app has stopped.`

Then I tried to find the error using `app-debug( ./gradlew assembleDebug )`, and got this:

[image]

It says `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'r.default.manifest.env')`

My dependencies are as below:

```
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "^20.0.0",
    "native-base": "^2.3.1",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "^0.47.0",
    "react-native-navbar": "^2.0.1",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11"
  }
```

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: Did u get any solution?

Comment: @tsagita Any solution??

Answer (score 0):

So the cause of error is just stupid.

The issue with **React-Navigation**
In **node_modules/react-navigation/src/navigators/DrawerNavigator.js** there is imported TabRouter, which seems like component (starts with upper case), but in reality is just function, so when the code reaches const contentRouter = TabRouter(routeConfigs, tabsConfig); it throws that error because it does not resolve it as function? It does not even run it.
This is some new babel config stuff or something, which is just weird space of js for me...

So one way to fix this is to rename all **TabRouter** in that file to **tabRouter**. 
I hate to modify node_modules files but this is only way that I found to fix this error.
Its working for me.